# ArcMap 10.7.1 Error: Please enter a number between X and X

Tags: arcmap, layouts

I use ArcMap 10.7.1

I get repeatedly a "stupid" but very annoying error message: "Please enter a number between X and X". Numbers which are requested to type in vary from 0 to 100, -360 to 360 or 0 to -32767.

This happens when I click on the symbol of a feature class to edit its design. Lets say my outline width is 2,00 and I want to change it so I click on the arrow. Then the error message appears. After clicking "OK" it might change outline width to 100 or do some other stuff which seems random to me.

The problem is solved by restarting the program but reappears after some minutes/operations.

The punctuation setting should be correct.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible corruption in normal.mxt?

Comment: I changed the decimal separation in the Windows 10 settings from "." to ",". Seems like it did the trick. I am confused anyways because I was told by my Prof. to change it from "," to ".". Maybe calculation operations need "." and the layout works better with "," ? I am in Europe.